# How to fetch integrated versions field in jira ticket via REST API?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

How to fetch integrated versions field present in Jira ticket via REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *Integrated Version* field is probably a custom field based on project version. The field is identified by its ID (e.g. `customfield_10500`).

If you use common REST API method to retrieve a Jira issue, you can see the field in the JSON response:
`https://jira.domain.com/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-123`

```json
"fields": {
  ...
  "customfield_10500": [
    {
      "self": "https://jira.domain.com/rest/api/2/version/21787",
      "id": "21787",
      "name": "8.0.3.0",
      "archived": false,
      "released": false
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

You can limit the request to get only that specific custom field only:
`https://jira.domain.com/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-123?fields=customfield_10500`

To retrieve all available project versions, you need to retrieve all project versions: https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.5.13/#api/2/project-getProjectVersions

Answer (score 0):

fixVersion is a part of a Jira issue. So for that purposes it's possible to get using get issue rest request.
Here's a reference from atlassian doc: https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.5.13/#api/2/issue-getIssue

To grab only fixVersion field and its data, it will look like:

`https://jira_url/rest/api/2/issue/$ISSUE_KEY?fields=fixVersions`

Comment: I know how to fetch fix-versions.I need integrated-versions where the fix has already gone into.

Comment: There is no field called 'integrated versions' or 'integrated-versions' in Jira by default. It may be a custom field that a Jira admin has created. Do a [Get request to the /rest/api/{apiVersion}/field endpoint](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-fields/#api-rest-api-3-field-get) to get a list of all the fields in your Jira instance, with their names and their IDs.